# Is my understanding of async functions wrong ? Why do I get the following behaviour?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I've looked into a few other SO posts but none really answered my question, and chatGPT isn't being very helpful either...

Consider the following Javascript (and not Typescript!) code :

```
exports.getValue = async (param1) => {
  const snapshot = await someFunction1();   //someFunction1 definitely returns a Promise, it's from a known API
  return snapshot.get("received");  //get returns any (so it could be undefined)
};
```

At this point, my function 1) is defined as `async` 2) has an `await` call inside it 3) has the following info when I hover on it : `(property) alreadyReceived: (param1: any) => Promise<any>`.

Now in some other file, inside an async function, I want to call this function. So, naturally, I write

```
const booleanValueINeed = await getValue(myArg);
```

However here, I get the following warning from VS Code `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. ts(80007)`. In my opinion, the `await` *is* warranted.

Notice how this is a TypeScript warning, even though I'm in a `.js` file. What's weird is I have been writing quite a lot of async code and I haven't got the warning whenever it indeed wasn't warranted.

As suggested in another post, I also tried adding a JSDOC (`/* returns {Promise<boolean>`}, but it didn't change a thing.

Any idea why I get this behaviour ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to know why you're getting that behavior or do you want to know when a function is considered async like your title suggests?

Comment: Is `await getValue(myArg);` inside an async function?

Comment: @possum I guess the behaviour, I modified the title to be more precise, but to be fair one question is subdued to another: if I understand when a function is considered async, then I should be able to deduct why I get this behaviour

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes mb I forgot to mention it, I added the precision in the post

Comment: Assuming that `getValue` really references the one you defined above, and is not shadowed by another definition, your code is fine, and the IDE warning is wrong.

Comment: @trincot Alright, weird then, thank you for you answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A function is considered async in 2 cases:

1. returns a promise
2. declared with `async` (which makes it to return a promise resolved to the returned value)

`await` is not necessary. It just allows to wait for a promise being resolved inside a function with `async` postponing execution of the code after it. Also works in the top level of ES modules.

When you apply `await` to a non promise, probably Typescript could tell that this has NO effect - since no promise to wait. But that's not true, `await` postpones the next code into a JS microtask and it is executed async. As you can see everything after `await` is postponed even a non promise value is used after `await`.

Seems `getValue()` isn't async (as determined by Typescript) so you can remove `async/await` as not needed. Or Typescript failed to infer.

```js
(async () => {
  
  await queueMicrotask(() => console.log('before await'));
  console.log('after await')

})();
```

Without `await`:

```js
(async () => {
  
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('before await'));
  console.log('after await')

})();
```

Comment: fair enough I suppose you answered my poorly phrased title instead of my post, that's on me. That being said, do you agree in my scenario, the await keyword *is* warranted since my function is declared with `async`?

Comment: @caldera added an extra example with `await`

Comment: @caldera added an example without `await`

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer, but this doesn't answer (or perhaps I don't understand how it is related to) why in the scenario I defined, the `await` in `const booleanValueINeed = await getValue(myArg);` is deemed useless even though `getValue` is defined as `async` thus returning a Promise. Or are you implying that the warning I get is simply wrong and my understanding is correct ?

Comment: @caldera my guess our `getValue` isn't async so that's why the warning. in that case you don't async/await. but using `await` has an effect that could be needed as described in my code snippet examples

Comment: I copied your first snippet in my editor, and I also get the warning, so I assume the warning is wrong and I will just accept that as is. Thank you for answering!

Comment: but not only do I define `getValue` with the `async` keyword, but I also call (and await) a Promise-returning function inside of it (what I call "someFunction" actually is [this function](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/documentreference#_google_cloud_firestore_DocumentReference_get_member_1_) from firebase API to be precise) so the function *has* to be async right ?

Comment: I accepted your answer as you asked because it ended up being the most helpful, but I would suggest editing it so that it gives a clear answer to my question : ie. the warning is not warranted and this should be considered as an error from Typescript.

Comment: @caldera yes, i would consider it as a Typescript error. in my experience Typescript is quite buggy